# Write a program that takes in a line of text as input, and outputs that line of text in reverse

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program that takes in a line of text as input, and outputs that line of text in reverse. The program repeats, ending when the user enters "Quit", "quit", or "q" for the line of text.

Ex: If the input is:

> Hello there
>
> Hey
>
> quit

then the output is:

> ereht olleH
>
> yeH

I tried like this but it instead of break loop continues. Anyone please tell me what I am missing

```
user_input = input()

while True:

       values = user_input
       
       if values == 'quit' or values == 'Quit' or values == 'q':
        
            break
        
       print(values[::-1])
```

My output comes as

> ereht olleH
>
> ereht olleH
>
> ereht olleH
>
> ereht olleH
>
> ereht olleH
>
> ereht olleH

...and continues

Comment: this doesn't look like you are asking anything

Comment: It seems you ask for input only once, before entering the loop. should you ask again inside the loop?

Comment: @Knut Forkalsrud-- same result happened, if I put that out side of loop.

Comment: Try it *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the user_input with the next input

For example (in java):

```
String userInput = kb.nextLine();

while (true) 
{
   String check = userInput;
   if (check.equals("quit") || check.equals("Quit") || check.equals("q")) {
      break;
   } 

   String reverse = "";
   for (int i = userInput.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       reverse = reverse + userInput.charAt(i);
   }

   System.out.println(reverse);
   userInput = kb.nextLine(); 
}
```